# Transpose and reshape a 3d array in matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization

Suppose I have an array X of size n by p by q. I would like to reshape it as a matrix with p rows, and in each row put the concatenation of the n rows of size q, resulting in a matrix of size p by nq.

I managed to do it with a loop but it takes a while say if n=1000, p=300, q=300.

```
F0=[];
for k=1:size(F,1)
    F0=[F0,squeeze(X(k,:,:))];
end
```

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
Y = reshape(permute(X, [2 1 3]), size(X,2), []);
```

Example with `n=2`, `p=3`, `q=4`:

```
>> X
X(:,:,1) =
     0     6     9
     8     3     0
X(:,:,2) =
     4     7     1
     3     7     4
X(:,:,3) =
     4     7     2
     6     7     6
X(:,:,4) =
     6     1     9
     1     4     3

>> Y = reshape(permute(X, [2 1 3]), size(X,2), [])
Y =
     0     8     4     3     4     6     6     1
     6     3     7     7     7     7     1     4
     9     0     1     4     2     6     9     3
```

Comment: Don't you need another permute of `[1 3 2]`?

Comment: @Divakar Hmm... not sure how the OP wanted it, actually.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks! You already have my +1 too for looking deeper into the problem. I guess there are two possible ways to linearize the two remaining dimensions, and that our answers differ in that

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
reshape(permute(X,[2 3 1]),p,[])
```

Thus, for code verification, one can look into a sample case run -

```
n = 2;
p = 3;
q = 4;

X = rand(n,p,q)
F0=[];
for k=1:n
    F0=[F0,squeeze(X(k,:,:))];
end
F0

F0_noloop = reshape(permute(X,[2 3 1]),p,[])
```

Output is -

```
F0 =
    0.4134    0.6938    0.3782    0.4775    0.2177    0.0098    0.7043    0.6237
    0.1257    0.8432    0.7295    0.2364    0.3089    0.9223    0.2243    0.1771
    0.7261    0.7710    0.2691    0.8296    0.7829    0.0427    0.6730    0.7669
F0_noloop =
    0.4134    0.6938    0.3782    0.4775    0.2177    0.0098    0.7043    0.6237
    0.1257    0.8432    0.7295    0.2364    0.3089    0.9223    0.2243    0.1771
    0.7261    0.7710    0.2691    0.8296    0.7829    0.0427    0.6730    0.7669
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using vectorization to solve the problem, you could look at the code to try and figure out what may improve performance.  In this case, since you know the size of your output matrix `F0` should be px(n*q), you could pre-allocate memory to `F0` and avoid the constant resizing of the matrix at each iteration of the `for` loop

```
n=1000; 
p=300; 
q=300;

F0=zeros(p,n*q);

for k=1:size(F,1)
    F0(:,(k-1)*q+1:k*q) = squeeze(F(k,:,:));
end
```

While probably not as efficient as the other two solutions, it is an alternative.  Try the above and see what happens!